# How to compare instances subclasses of @dataclass with same inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I am trying to compare two dataclasses that inherit from a common base class (also a @dataclass).

The fields of the inherited classes are specific to them and are not considered in the comparison; I want to compare only the base class attributes.

Here is my attempt:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass(order=True)
class Base:
    a: float

@dataclass(order=True)
class ChildA(Base):
    attribute_a: str = field(compare=False)

@dataclass(order=True)
class ChildB(Base):
    attribute_b: str = field(compare=False)


ca = ChildA(1, 'a')
cb = ChildB(2, 'b')
ca < cb
```

However, I get:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'ChildA' and 'ChildB'
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: The generated comparison methods always require the arguments to have the exact same type; separate subclasses of a common ancestor cannot be compared. See https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/dataclasses.py#L575. You'l have to define `Base.__lt__` et al yourself (though see `functools.total_ordering` to make that a little easier, by only requiring `__eq__` and one other method to generate the rest).

Comment: > "The generated comparison methods always require the arguments to have the exact same type"
Is this true even when I set field(compare=False)? Shouldn't those fields be discarded in the comparison method?

Answer (score 5):

You should define the comparison methods for `Base` yourself; the methods created by `dataclass` require the arguments to have the *exact* same type.

```
from functools import total_ordering

@total_ordering
@dataclass(eq=False)
class Base:
    a: float


    # Both of these are oversimplified. At the very
    # least, handle the error resulting from `other`
    # not having an `a` attribute.

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.a == other.a

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.a < other.a
```

Comment: thanks for that. However, since I am setting the fields in the subclass with `field(compare=False)`, shouldn't these different types be discarded during comparison?
According to https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/dataclasses.py#L959, shouldn't these attributes be filtered out, before `_cmp_fn` is called?

Comment: No. Before even looking at the fields, the [comparison function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/dataclasses.py#L575) compares the value of each argument's `__class__` attribute for *object identity*. Only after confirming that both are, say, `ChildA` instances does it compare the selected attribute values.

Comment: I see. Thanks for that. This goes beyond this question, but do you think it's worth opening a feature request/bug, so that subclasses can be supported in the object identity check?

Answer (score 0):

```py
ca.a < cb.a
```

Both have the attribute 'a' from the parent class, access the attribute using '.a'

Comment: This was a simplified example that just had one comparable attribute. What if I have more complex dataclasses, with more attributes? Of course I can still group them in a tuple (e.g. `(ca.a, ca.b, ca.c) < (cb.a, ca.b, ca.c)`), but I was wondering if there is a more direct method?

Comment: Oh I see, I'll bookmark the question and come back to it later