# Compare integer values of two different class objects

Tags: python, class, object, integer, boolean

I got a python code now (thanks a lot scotty3785):

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class House:
   Address: str
   Bedrooms: int
   Bathrooms: int
   Garage: bool
   Price: float
   def getPrice(self):
        print(self.Price)
        
   def newPrice(self, newPrice):
        self.Price = newPrice
   def __str__(self):
        if self.Garage==1:
             x="Attached garage"
        else:
             x="No garage"
        return f"""{self.Address}
        Bedrooms: {self.Bedrooms} Bathrooms: {self.Bathrooms}
        {x}
        Price: {self.Price}"""


    h1 = House("1313 Mockingbird Lane", 3, 2.5, True, 300000)        
    h2 = House("0001 Cemetery Lane", 4, 1.75, False, 400000)

    print(h1)
    print(h2)
    h1.newPrice(500000)
    h1.getPrice()
    h2<h1
```

Now I need to compare the prices of both h1 and h2 using `h2<h1` and give a Boolean as output.

Comment: Does [this answer help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64483198/2280890)? It indicates you need to define your own comparison functions, in a similar way that you've defined `__str__`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either implement the special method `__lt__` on your class or pass the `order` and `eq` arguments as `True` to the `dataclass` decorator(be aware that it will compare your elements as tuple). So you should have something like this:

```py
@dataclass(eq=True, order=True)
class House:
   Address: str
   Bedrooms: int
   Bathrooms: int
   Garage: bool
   Price: float
   # your code...
```

or, the most appropriate to your case:

```py
@dataclass(order=True)
class House:
   Address: str
   Bedrooms: int
   Bathrooms: int
   Garage: bool
   Price: float
   
   def __lt__(self, other_house):
      return self.Price < other_house.Price
```

Comment: Thanks, the second method worked more easily